# A Properly Formated Mysql Query for Python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I'm struggling with the formatting on a mysql query and I was hoping you could point me in the right direction. Here are the queries

```
sql = "SELECT price FROM inventory WHERE card_name = %s AND card_set = %s"
sql_rare = "SELECT rarity FROM inventory WHERE card_name = %s AND card_set = %s"
sql_count = "SELECT count(*) FROM inventory WHERE card_name = %s AND card_set = %s
```

When I run the following code, utilizing the sql_count query, i get an error saying:

> File "C:\Users\Spencer\Desktop\Python Programs\PythonMTG\Revision3AutoAndManual\51515\magicassistantcsv.py", line 264, in output_card
>       for row in getmtgprice.query(sql_count, ([card_name, set_name])):
>   TypeError: query() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)

Here is the code producing this error:

```
getmtgprice = PriceCheck()
        for row in getmtgprice.query(sql_count, ([card_name, set_name])):  
            if row[0] ==0:
            priced_card = '0.00'
```

And here is the PriceCheck function:

```
class PriceCheck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root',     passwd='', db='mscan')
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()

    def query(self, arg, cardname, setname):
        self.c.execute(arg, cardname, setname)
        return self.c

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()
```

Do you see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `query` method takes separate arguments for `cardname` and `setname`, not a list containing both. So, instead of:

```
for row in getmtgprice.query(sql_count, ([card_name, set_name])):
```

You should have:

```
for row in getmtgprice.query(sql_count, card_name, set_name):
```